# Call to custom EXE from .NET MVC website throwing error

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, runtime-error

My MVC 4 website code is calling a custom exe file on a server to perform some operation. It works fine on my local and QA server but on a Live server it works once and after that throws the below entry in event log:

> .NET Framework runtime error: “There was a failure initializing profiling API attach infrastructure. This process will not allow a profiler to attach. HRESULT: 0x80004005”.

Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Add 'a' where needed, other wording

Comment: Such more information might be interesting, such as: What is the code that spawns this .exe? Is this .exe in a network share?

Comment: EXE is called from controller method and its generating custom PDF/CSV files and storing them into folder on server. EXE stored folder is network shared. A weird thing is its working first time (say after 30 minutes) and then throwing above said exception for all other requests.